# Using ApplicationService layer from another project ABP

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I have added another project to my ABP and I need to access to ApplicationService methods, I've created a module for my new project here is the code

```
[DependsOn(
    typeof(PrestamosApplicationModule), 
    typeof(PrestamosEntityFrameworkCoreModule))]
public class ReportsApplicationModule : AbpModule
{

    public ReportsApplicationModule(PrestamosEntityFrameworkCoreModule abpZeroTemplateEntityFrameworkCoreModule)
    {
        abpZeroTemplateEntityFrameworkCoreModule.SkipDbContextRegistration = true;
    }
    
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(typeof(ReportsApplicationModule).GetAssembly());
        //ServiceCollectionRegistrar.Register(IocManager);

    }

    public override void PreInitialize()
    {
        base.PreInitialize();
    }
}
```

The Program.cs class

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
          .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
          {
              var abpBootstrapper = AbpBootstrapper.Create<ReportsApplicationModule>();
              services.AddSingleton(abpBootstrapper);
              WindsorRegistrationHelper.CreateServiceProvider(abpBootstrapper.IocManager.IocContainer, services);

          });
}
```

My problem is when I want to use an AppService

```
   public ReporteClienteController(IClienteAppService clienteAppService)
    {
        _clienteAppService = clienteAppService;
    }
```

I got the following error

InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'DomiSys.Prestamos.Generales.ClienteNs.IClienteAppService' while attempting to activate 'DomiSys.Prestamos.Reports.Controllers.ReporteClienteController'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)
lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , object[] )
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider+<>c__DisplayClass5_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

What is wrong?, how can I configure the module correctly to use the depence Injection ?

Comment: I think it's a bad design convention to use/share app services if you want common methods we should use the Managers for that

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing `PrestamosApplicationModule` with `PrestamosCoreModule`.

And I guess that part of code is not necessary

```
 .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
          {
              var abpBootstrapper = AbpBootstrapper.Create<ReportsApplicationModule>();
              services.AddSingleton(abpBootstrapper);
              WindsorRegistrationHelper.CreateServiceProvider(abpBootstrapper.IocManager.IocContainer, services);

          });
```