# Module in Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to bootstrap an ABP module in an Azure Function but I get an error:
`Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException: 'No component for supporting the service System.IServiceProvider was found'`

**Stack Trace**

```
[].EntityFrameworkCore.dll![].EntityFrameworkCore.Seed.SeedHelper.WithDbContext<[].EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext>(Abp.Dependency.IIocResolver iocResolver, System.Action<[].EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext> contextAction) Line 79
[].EntityFrameworkCore.dll![].EntityFrameworkCore.Seed.SeedHelper.SeedHostDb(Abp.Dependency.IIocResolver iocResolver) Line 35
[].EntityFrameworkCore.dll![].EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkModule.PostInitialize() Line 46
```

So in the Function's Startup.Configure I use `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder` to initialize the module.  Everything seems to go great until the EntityFrameworkModule tries to complete initializing and seed the DB.  That's when I get the error above.

**Here is my code:**

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(JobProcessor.Startup))]
namespace JobProcessor
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {

        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    var abpBootstrapper = AbpBootstrapper.Create<JobProcessorModule>();
                    services.AddSingleton(abpBootstrapper);
                    abpBootstrapper.Initialize();
                })
                .UseCastleWindsor(IocManager.Instance.IocContainer)
                .Build()
                .Run();
        }
    }
}

namespace JobProcessor
{
    [DependsOn(
        typeof(EntityFrameworkModule),
        typeof(CoreModule),
        typeof(AbpAspNetCoreModule)
    )]
    public class JobProcessorModule : AbpModule
    {
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(typeof(JobProcessorModule).GetAssembly());
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you added some entity to your project? check if you forgot to add it to DbContext

Comment: @JoséPolanco I appreciate you commenting.  Unfortunately the issue seems to be with dependency injection not working.  This is an existing project and does have entities, I'm just trying to add another project to it.

Comment: Ooh, if you’re adding a new project, verify to put the [(DependsOn)] tag, this tag must be added on the new module file, you can check the default modules that already have it.

Comment: You can check at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62660804/10138953 I this is the same issue that you have

Comment: @JoséPolanco I'll take a look next time I can work on that project.  Appreciate that!